# Fetch POST cannot pass body as JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I am trying to call an express endpoint with fetch from my react app and pass the body as a JSON object so that I can include more data within it. The call currently works when I set body directly to token.id, but I want to include more data. For now I'm just constructing the JSON with that one piece of data, but cannot seem to get the server to properly handle it. I have the working lines of code commented out, which I know work as I am seeing the calls make it through to the stripe API. With the new code I get as far as the token creation working, but the create customer call does not show up on the stripe API.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {CardElement, injectStripe} from 'react-stripe-elements';

class CheckoutForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {complete: false};
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  async submit(ev) {
    let {token} = await this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"});

    let data ={
        id: token.id
    }

    let response = await fetch("/charge", {
        method: "POST",
        //Works with the commented code
        //headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
        //body: token.id,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(response => response.json());
    if (response.ok) console.log("Purchase Complete!")
    if (response.ok) this.setState({complete: true});
    }

  render() {
    if (this.state.complete) return <h1>Purchase Complete</h1>;
    return (
      <div className="checkout">
        <p>Would you like to complete the purchase?</p>
        <CardElement />
        <button onClick={this.submit}>Send</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
```

This is my server code:

```
const app = require("express")();
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_oE2EqjsM7mWqgRRwaomptrdX");

app.use(require("body-parser").text());

app.post("/charge", jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var userdata = JSON.parse(req.body);
        let {status} = stripe.customers.create({
            description: "Test Person",
            //Commented code currently works
            //source: req.body
            //Below is how I expected this to work when passing the body as JSON
            source: userdata.id
        });
        res.json({status});
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).end();
      }
    });

app.listen(9000, () => console.log("Listening on port 9000"));
```

Comment: Are there any errors in either console?

Comment: you're running `if (response.ok) console.log("Purchase Complete!")` **outside** the fetch promise chain - and completely disregarding `response.json()` anyway

Comment: Removing those two if (response.ok) lines fixed it. I'm still a little iffy on how that was preventing the data from reaching my server. But thanks for bringing up that those were the problem!